# How to set different theme for different store in opencart in multistore installation?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have installed multi-store in my open cart installation. I want to set different theme for my two different stores. I have copied the /catalog/view/theme/default folder and renamed it to mytheme. But still this mytheme is not added to store theme drop down option.

Can any one please explain, how it will possible ?

Comment: Which OC version?

Comment: OpenCart Version 2.3.0.2 @Mojtaba Sabeti

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default theme has these files in admin folder, you need to create these file for your new theme.

```
admin/controller/extension/theme/theme_default.php
admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/theme_default.php
admin/view/template/extension/theme/theme_default.tpl
```

Don't forget to edit them and replace `theme_default` with `mytheme`, for example:

```
class ControllerExtensionThemeThemeDefault extends Controller {
```

edit it to:

```
class ControllerExtensionMytheme extends Controller {
```

After create above files go to `Extensions/Extensions` and select `Themes` from deopdown menu, here you must see your theme setting, now you can enable it.
When you enable it, you can assign it to your store from `system/settings`

[image]

Comment: Yes it works ....But a error is showing in my send store "Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!" . I have assigned the theme in the store setting.

Comment: Did you assign theme to store from system/settings/yourStore, did you enable theme?

Comment: Got this error while install/uninstall the theme also Class 'ControllerExtensionMytheme' not found in /system/engine/action.php

Comment: yes, I have enabled the theme in system/settings/myStore

Comment: also make sure you have set `Theme Directory` to your theme folder, in theme settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128778/discussion-between-lipsa-and-mojtaba-sabeti).

Comment: Did you guys find a solution to this? I have exactly same situation: copied all the files and updated settings but now I get the same Error text on frontend. @Lipsa ? Would be useful to post the final solution here.

Comment: False alarm, hadn't changed all the theme_default texts in the controller file. Still wondering why the page loads the default theme stylesheet anyway...